# How to put a image behind text(or table) without use the background clausule html

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I want to put a image behind a table (as watermark) and then print it (using IE, but using a background doesn't work even activating background print).

I was trying to use an `img` tag and play with the position (relative, absolute and fixed) to put it behind the table.

This is how I open and print the page

```
 function PrintThisDiv(id) {
    var HTMLContent = document.getElementById(id);
    var Popup = window.open('about:blank', id);

    Popup.document.writeln('<html><head><title>Imprime Tiquetes</title>');
    Popup.document.writeln('<style type="text/css" media="print">');
    //Popup.document.writeln('.no-print{display: none;}');
    //Popup.document.writeln('@page{margin: 0;}');
    Popup.document.writeln('</style>');
    Popup.document.writeln('</head><body style:"position:fixed" onload = "window.print();window.close();">');
    Popup.document.writeln("<img src='../Img/reimpreso.PNG' width=100% height=100% alt='Repeating Background Image' style='position:relative' />");

    //Popup.document.writeln('<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.print();">Imprimir</a>');
    Popup.document.writeln(HTMLContent.innerHTML);
    Popup.document.writeln('</body   ></html>');
    Popup.document.close();
    Popup.focus();
}
```

table

```
<table width='200px' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style=\"border: thin solid #000000; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-size: 8.25px\">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic sample:

https://plnkr.co/edit/5RKsxTL60x7dWwRrb03l?p=preview

```
<div style="position:relative;">
   <img  style="width:200px;height:200px;" src='data:image/png;base64,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'>
   <table style="width:300px;height:200px;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;" border=1><tr><td>item1</td><td>item2</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

You have to put both table and image in the same level of some div. Have div at relative positioning, so that you can position child elements absolute to it.